# Problem with \underbrace and Libertinus Math

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode-math

I just switched to Libertinus Math and now have a problem with an `\underbrace`! While using Latin Modern as math font I get the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[
    math-style=ISO,
    bold-style=ISO,
    partial=upright,
    nabla=upright
]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
FAT-16: \[\underbrace{\text{16-Bit}}_{\mathclap{\text{Größe einer Adresse (für das Speichern der Dateien)}}}\text{-Dateisystem}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe pic 1]

After switching to Libertinus Math the `\underbrace` has a wrong size:

[image: mwe pic 2]

Any idea how to fix it?

---

(ed.) minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\begin{document}
\[\underbrace{z}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzzzz}_{a}\]
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image]

Surprisingly, xelatex exhibits different output which fails less often:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\begin{document}
\[\underbrace{z}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzzz}_{a}\]
\[\underbrace{zzzzzzz}_{a}\]
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

---

Here is using with the Libertinus as in TeXLive 2018 current pretest, updated. Things are much better but still a bit strange for `zzz`. In images below, maybe I have one more lines, because I extended mwe in the meantime.

With xetex at left and luatex at right:

[image][image]

Comment: I have added more minimal example. There is also a problem with xelatex.... (I thought at first only lualatex)

Comment: works okay for me with the newest version of the font (in texlive 2018).

Comment: Works for me too (xelatex and lualatex)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer confirmed on my updated TeXLive 2018. Strange line spacing discrepancy between xetex and luatex output (luatex's one is less spread out)

Comment: @Josef I hope you don't mind all my edits to your post.

Comment: side note: It looks as if underbrace width can increase only step-wise, explaining sort of that some cases such as `zzz` look sub-optimal. Loading or not mathtools changes nothing.

Comment: @jfbu No, as long as you solve my problem! ;-) I can confirm the massive difference between xelatex and lualatex with TL2017

Comment: thus as first pointed by @UlrikeFischer it looks as if you only need latest Libertinus update. The images at bottom were taken with compilation using updated TL2018 pretest.

Comment: @jfbu My plan was to install TL2018 pretest in my Easter holidays anyway. So at least my problem seems to vanish next week! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(moved from comments)

The issue seems non-existent with latest Libertinus Math release, as currently available in TeXLive 2018 (pretest, libertinus texlive package having rev number `47077`).

The version seems to be Version 6.5 from FontBook info field (Mac OS).
And from the CTAN annoucement Version:  6.5  2018-03-21